# htaccess redirect repeats folder in URL over and over?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect camping.website.com to website.com/camping. I have an .htaccess file under the subdomain on my server with this rule:

```
Redirect 301 / https://website.com/camping/
```

With the slash on the end like above, the URL it returns is:

```
https://website.com/camping/camping/camping/camping/camping/camping/camping/
```

If I remove the slash on the end, it will return this instead:

```
https://website.com/campingcamping
```

If I change the destination URL to anything else, the redirect works normally. It's only when I have the word "camping" that it messes up. Is there some kind of conflict because the folder I'm trying to redirect to is the same as the subdomain?

Edit: I should mention something else. The following redirect:

```
Redirect 301 /category/camping-parks/ https://website.com/camping/camping-parks/
```

Returns this:

```
https://website.com/campingcamping/camping-parks/
```

Strange, huh?

Comment: do the domain and sub domain in same server ?

Comment: Yes they're on the same server

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is within this rule :

```
Redirect 301 / https://website.com/camping/
```

Will catch both domain and subdomain requests as you commented that they are in same server.

Try this using `mod_rewrite`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?camping\.website\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://website.com/camping/$1 [L,R=301]
```

**Note:** clear browser cache then test